# How to prevent files from opening automatically while using Live Share on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

When multiple users are coding a project and one user opens a file, the same file is opened for all other users. This becomes really annoying as several files get stacked in your VS code app. Is there a way to disable this?